# Error from ps.map in GRASS. How to fix?

Tags: grass-gis, error

I'm trying to learn how to use [`ps.map`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/ps.map.html) in GRASS. I thought that running it in interactive mode from the command line would be a good place to start, but I'm getting the following error:

```
> ps.map                                                                                 ~
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/wxpython/gui_modules/menuform.py", line 59, in <module>
    import globalvar
  File "/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/wxpython/gui_modules/globalvar.py", line 76, in <module>
    import wx
  File "/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/wx/_core_.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/wx/_core_.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

UPDATE: In response to Markus's comment that terminal messages on GRASS startup might help to diagnose the problem, the following two chunks provides all terminal output from GRASS startup.

Chunk 1: from starting /Applications/Grass-6.4.app to GUI Startup window.

```
Last login: Sat Mar 23 10:08:40 on ttys002
gregory@Gregorys-MacBook> '/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'; exit
Rebuilding Addon HTML manual pages index...
Rebuilding Addon menu...
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/osascript) is code signed with entitlements
Python 2.6.7 found.
Cleaning up temporary files ...
Starting GRASS ...
```

Chunk 2: from selecting a location/mapset in the GUI startup window and clicking "Start GRASS".

```
          __________  ___   __________    _______________
         / ____/ __ \/   | / ___/ ___/   / ____/  _/ ___/
        / / __/ /_/ / /| | \__ \\_  \   / / __ / / \__ \ 
       / /_/ / _, _/ ___ |___/ /__/ /  / /_/ // / ___/ / 
       \____/_/ |_/_/  |_/____/____/   \____/___//____/  

Welcome to GRASS 6.4.2 (2012) 
GRASS homepage:                          http://grass.osgeo.org/
This version running thru:               shell (/bin/zsh)
Help is available with the command:      g.manual -i
See the licence terms with:              g.version -c
If required, restart the GUI with:       g.gui wxpython
When ready to quit enter:                exit

gregory@Gregorys-MacBook> Mar 23 11:31:05 Gregorys-MacBook.local pythonw2.6[2520] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Mar 23 11:31:05 Gregorys-MacBook.local pythonw2.6[2520] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Mar 23 11:31:05 Gregorys-MacBook.local pythonw2.6[2520] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Mar 23 11:31:05 Gregorys-MacBook.local pythonw2.6[2520] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Mar 23 11:31:05 Gregorys-MacBook.local pythonw2.6[2520] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: Which Mac OS X version do you use? "wrong architecture" looks like a version mixture.

Comment: @markusN Mac OS X version 10.8.3 Build 12D78. As for the GRASS version, I just did a fresh install of the required frameworks and GRASS itself from kyngchaos.com a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to start ps.map in interactive mode by specifying an output file. The syntax of the successful command was `ps.map output=out_file.ps`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the [framework packages](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software%3aframeworks) first, as suggested on http://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/mac-osx/ ? This may solve the problem.

Comment: I installed all the frameworks before I installed GRASS. The error log, presented in the original post, suggests that it's looking for an image not in a framework but in python/wx.

Comment: Just noticed that the GRASS version I installed from kyngchaos is known to have issues with the Python GUI in Mountain Lion, but it says that the command line modules should work fine. Ref: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/grass

Comment: I have notified him about this problem. Let's see...

Comment: William says: "Sounds like what's happening is that Python is running in 64bit mode somehow to run the option mini-gui interactive thing.  I tried it on a non-dev OS X 10.8, no error. Terminal messages on GRASS startup might help isolate the problem."

Comment: I edited the post to include the terminal messages on GRASS startup.

Comment: He asks: "There should be more before the normal GRASS Welcome message.  Need to scroll up.

Comment: I added all the terminal output from startup to the main body of the post.

Comment: Yes, thanks. William says: "Yes, that's what I had.  Maybe something in the shell environment (ie PATH), set from their .bash_profile, is interfering so it bypasses the 32bit python wrapper in GRASS.  The startup would still report the same Python version whether it runs directly or thru the wrapper.

Do any other commands work with just the command to bring up the interactive gui? (just to make sure that's where the problem is, and not only ps.map)"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how best to test that. Could you please suggest a specific command for me to try?

Comment: If you have a raster map, run "r.info rastermapname", for a vector map, run "v.info vectormapname"...

Comment: The command "r.info rastermapname" returned the expected information about the raster to the terminal, with no warnings or errors. It did not "bring up the interactive gui." It's not clear to me that it should have, however. Perhaps I misunderstood your previous comment. Should we move this to another forum? I'm content to keep this here, if it's the appropriate place.

Comment: Ah, my bad - I should have written that you launch the command without parameter to pop up the GUI, then select a map within it to see if it works.

Comment: Re: forum: the grass-user mailing list might be better since our Mac developers are reading there and could respond directly :)