# Can TimeManager animate a large number of rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, animation, timemanager

I understand that as of a year ago, the [TimeManager plugin was not intended to handle more than a handfull of rasters](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/21). This post is in blind hope that this has changed!

I'm trying to create a map with animated rasters and so far I'm having more success with TimeManager in QGIS than with my approach in GRASS (see related threads: [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55127/why-is-this-grass-script-from-grass-wiki-causing-an-error), [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55123/error-from-ps-map-in-grass-how-to-fix) on `ps.map` problems). I can create an animation with a few frames by using TimeManager, but the approach won't scale to thousands of frames as needed for two reasons:

1. I have to add the layers one at a time.
2. I have to enter the start time for each frame in the TimeManager panel. I had thought that it could automatically get the start time from the file names, which I created in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

I understand that raster support is new and somewhat less developed than vector support, but I'm hopeful that there's a way to automate this, which I have simply missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the situation hasn't changed and there are no immediate plans either. But any developer can pick up the code and enhance it.